# Insertar en varias tablas de mi DB datos con el mismo id en procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Hola me las he arreglado para hacer un registro de usuario en una app de ejercicios aunque no agrega el peso del usuario ni su altura ya que estos valores están en otras tablas:

**Tabla user**

```
[dbo].[Users]
(
        [UserID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [LoginName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [FirstName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [LastName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [SexIdent] [bit] NULL,
        [SomatotypeIdent] [int] NULL,
        [Age] [int] NULL,
        [LastLogIn] [date]
```

**Tabla Peso y Altura**

```
[dbo].[UserHeigth](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Heigth] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [date] NOT NULL
[dbo].[UserWeigth](
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Weigth] [float] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [date] NOT NULL
```

**PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO**

```
USE [FitnessApp]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[NuevoUsuario]    Script Date: 05/01/2021 20:26:47 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER proc [dbo].[NuevoUsuario]
@LoginName nvarchar(100),
@FirstName nvarchar(100),
@LastName nvarchar(100),
@SexIdent bit,
@SomatotypeIdent int,
@age int,
@lastlogin date

as

insert into Users values (@LoginName,@FirstName,@LastName,@SexIdent,@SomatotypeIdent,@age,@lastlogin)
```

Quisiera insertar valores en las otras tablas con el mismo id de usuario que se crea automáticamente cuando inserto valores a esa fila, pero no se si hacerlo en el mismo procedimiento almacenado sea la mejor idea

cabe destacar que coloco el peso y altura en otras tablas para así poder medir en graficas los cambios que hace el usuario ya que en vez de sobrescribir su peso y altura solo agrega un nuevo registro y se compara con los anteriores, espero puedan ayudarme con esto

Comment: Me parece que estas pidiendo más una opinión que una respuesta concreta. De cualquier forma, te hago algunos comentarios 1) Peso y alturas son entidades versionadas, pero a estas tablas les esta faltando una fecha por ejemplo la fecha de medición. 2) Puedes salvar peso y altura en el alta de un usuario, siempre que obviamente tengas esos datos en el alta 3) Para poder hacer lo anterior el SP debería tener los parametros de peso, altura y fecha de medición 4) además deberías incorporar todo en una transacción, para que la operación de alta en las tres tablas sea atómica.

Comment: 5) La idea de hacerlo todo en un  mismo es SP es razonable y adecuada siempre que se cumpla los dicho en (2), ahora si en la realidad, primero que  se hace es el alta de un usuario y luego en otra instancia distante en el tiempo, se hace la medición, ciertamente deberás dividir todo en dos instancias independientes.

Comment: esta manera crees que seria correcta? Crear el user con el sp de arriba luego consultar ese mismo user que acabo de crear e hacer la insersccion en las tablas foraneas?

Comment: Si en a instancia en la que das el alta ya sabes los datos de pesos o alturas, yo haría el alta del usuario y las medidas en el mismo Sp.

Answer (score 1):

Actualmente en el procedimiento no le pasas los valores de peso y altura, sería necesario incorporarlos como variables al llamar al procedimiento.

Después de realizar la primera inserción en la tabla de usuarios, debes capturar el valor del ID recién creado. Lo puedes hacer mediante `@@IDENTITY`

```
declare @UserID int
insert into Users values (@LoginName, @FirstName, @LastName, @SexIdent, @SomatotypeIdent, @age, @lastlogin)

SET @UserID = @@IDENTITY

insert into UserHeigth values (UserID, Heigth, LastUpdate)
values (@UserID, @Heigth, GetDate())

insert into UserWeigth values (UserID, Weigth, LastUpdate)
values (@UserID, @Weigth, GetDate())
```

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo pero al ejecutar el codigo me dice "Parameter @UserID  which was no suplied", lo hice como colocaste en el ejemplo y no capturo el Id :S

Comment: lo hice de esta manera :